# Retrieve images from firebase storage by path

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

Is it possible to retrieve images by a path other than URL? for example, I've saved my image in uid/profileImg.jpg so I can access the file by the user uid. I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a `StorageReference` to a file based on its path, use the `child` or `reference` methods. E.g.

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid

let userRef = storageRef.child(uid).child("profileImg.jpg")
```

Also see the section on [creating references](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference#create_a_reference) in the documentation.

**Update**: to make an image from the data in a `StorageReference`, have a look at this sample from the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#download_in_memory):

```
userRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

You might also want to look at [using FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui), which also handles client-side caching of the images.

All in all, I recommend spending some time studying the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start). A few hours spent there should answer most basic questions.

Comment: I'm familiar with references, but what I meant is how can I use userRef.getData to get data and convert it into an image

Comment: @user1512238 That's what this line *let image = UIImage(data: data!)* does. It takes data retrieved from Storage and converts it to an image.

Comment: @Jay I only added that snippet after the comment, but forgot to ping user1512238. Thanks for doing that for me. :)